# Fit.Polynomial Show func

Tags: math.net

I'm using `Fit.Polynomial` to fit my data and show by graph, and all works great, but I couldn't find way to present my `Y-function` to **any order**. If the function is order `2` so I want it to be presents as `y=ax^2+bx+c`, and if the order is `3` so function would be `y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d`.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Polynomial.Fit` which returns `Polynomial` instead of `Fit.Polynomial` which returns `double[]`.

```
var x = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var y = new double[] { 2, 5, 9 };

Console.WriteLine("Fit.Polynomial");
double[] @double = Fit.Polynomial(x, y, 2);
Console.WriteLine(@double);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", @double));

Console.WriteLine("\nPolynomial.Fit");
Polynomial polynomial = Polynomial.Fit(x, y, 2);
Console.WriteLine(polynomial);

Console.WriteLine("\nPolynomial.Fit");
Polynomial polynomial = Polynomial.Fit(x, y, 2);
Console.WriteLine(polynomial);
```

Gives

```
Fit.Polynomial
System.Double[]
0, 1.5, 0.500000000000001

Polynomial.Fit
1.5x + 0.500000000000001x^2
```